# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.sessionState

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to use spark in jupyter notebook. Here is my code and errors.
Thanks.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
     .master("local") \
     .appName("Image Retrieval") \
     .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
     .getOrCreate()
```

---

Error log:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.sessionState. :
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.(SparkSqlParser.scala:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.sqlParser$lzycompute(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.sqlParser(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:144)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:141)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: try removing  `config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")` method